# How would I use this linked-list file in the queue file using 'require'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list, queue

I want to use the LinkedList class in the Queue class through node.js 'require'. Basically, I would like to recreate a queue using the methods from LinkedList by having it be the internal data structure on Queue. Queue should work like the data structure of the same name, but through the use of a linked-list.

I tried setting a constructor in Queue that creates a linked-list and from there I would use its methods by calling them within the methods of the Queue class. The LinkedList class uses a Node class from another file for the creation of new nodes to apply to the linked-list, but that works fine.

```
// LinkedList file
let Node = require('./Node.js');

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }

  size() {
    let traveler = this.head;

    while (traveler) {
        traveler = traveler.next;
        this.length++;
    }
     return this.length;
   }

  append(value) {
    let newNode = new Node(value);

    if (!this.head) {
        this.head = newNode;
        this.length++;
        return;
    }

    let traveler = this.head;

    while (traveler.next) {
        traveler = traveler.next;
    }

    traveler.next = newNode;
    this.length++;
  }

}

// Queue file
let LinkedList = require('../linked-list/LinkedList');

class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.linkedList = new LinkedList();
  }

  enqueue(value) {
    this.linkedList.append(value);
 }

  size() {
    return this.linkedList.size();
 }

  isEmpty() {
    let queueSize = this.linkedList.size();

    return queueSize === 0;
   }
}
```

If I call queue.enqueue(5) three times, for example, I would expect to have a made a linked-list with three nodes each with the value 5 and the last one pointing to null, just like a normal linked-list. Right now I get the following output when I console.log this.linkedList:
head: Node { value: 5, next: Node { value: 5, next: [Node] } }, length: 6 }
I'm not sure why length is 6 and why the second node points to [Node]. Length should be 3.

Comment: what does ```Queue.size()``` return?

Comment: and why doesn't ```LinkedList.size()``` return ```this.length```, what's the point of storing it when you aren't going to use it?

Comment: In your LinkedList file you need to write export in front of class LinkedList and then you will be able to access its methods.

Comment: Forgot to add that I did export LinkedList, although I didn't include it in the code here. Accessing the methods from LinkedList works just fine, it is the returned values that are incorrect. Queue.size() should return the length of the queue. I'm not sure what you mean Danyal, LinkedList.size() does return this.length, it is right after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

On LinkedList I had this.length increment both in size and for other methods. This resulted in double the length of what it actually was. I simply removed everything in LinkedList.size() except for 'return this.length;'.